# Why Swift Filter by Month shows wrong result

Tags: swift

I trying to filter array based on date. Why it filter wrong month,

```
extension Date {
        init(month: Int, day: Int, year: Int) {
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.month = month
            dateComponents.day = day
            dateComponents.year = year
            self = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents) ?? Date()
        }
        var month: Int {
            return cal.component(.month, from: self)
            
        }
    }
    let cal =  Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    let sampleArr = [Date(month: 09, day: 30, year: 2023),Date(month: 10, day: 1, year: 2023) ]
    let filterArr = sampleArr.filter{ $0.month == 10}
    print(filter)
```

1. [2023-09-30 19:00:00 +0000] //fillterArr show this result WHY
2. [2023-10-01 19:00:00 +0000] // it supposed to show this only bcz month is 10

Why swift behave like this ?

Comment: You use `Calendar.current` in `init` but `Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)` in the other code. This might cause problems. Also, as 30 Sept is last day of the month, it could be a time zone issue.

Comment: @Chris I think got it. I just tested, replaced `cal` with `Calendar.current`, and it works as expected.

Comment: Try `print(filterArr.map { $0.description(with: .current) } )` to print the date with your locale (and time zone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact returning the October date. But when you print the date, it is showing it in a different timezone (UTC?) and/or without daylight saving, so it appears as September.

Try changing the September date to January and you will see that the output doesn't change.

Or change the October date to 02 Oct and you will see that the printed date is 01 Oct.

Answer (score 1):

I’m converting my comment to an answer as OP said it helped.

---

You use `Calendar.current` in init but `Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)` in the other code.

Try making both `Calendar.current`.